# ipython arrow up gives me old history

Tags: python, ipython

Recently ipython has started to act very oddly. I am using version 8.20 now. If I press arrow-up, instead of giving me the most recent line it gives me something from a long time in the past.

How can I fix this?

I am on ubuntu 20.04.

Here is a transcript:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: x=2                                                                                                                               

In [2]: %history                                                                                                                          
x=2
%history

In [3]: random.choices(range(2), weights=probs)
```

The [3] line comes from pressing the up arrow.

Comment: How are you running it? Do you have multiple instances running?

Comment: @tripleee just run ipython from the command line. Only one instance running.

Comment: You wouldn't have had the first letter i.e. `r` typed in the input line before you pressed the up arrow, have you?

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні No I didn't. I have in fact now seen this on two different computers.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with IPython 8.2.0 on debian.

Comment: I've ran into this later, though. At one point the up arrow started to produce old lines (ironically, the test lines from this question). The %history is intact though. It started to happen when my HDD was very busy extracting a 22 GB archive, which might not be relevant. There seem to be relevant issues on the issue tracker: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13631 https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13635

Answer (score 6):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13631) [introduced in IPython 8.2.0](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/13592), which [has been fixed](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/13657/) [in 8.3.0](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version8.html).

Comment: I'm still (again?) seeing this behaviour in 8.5.0.

Comment: @Seb: I've just installed 8.5.0 and have the same issue.

Comment: I just updated to 8.7.0 (currently latest) and the issue was resolved for me

Comment: This is also found in `8.12.2` with Python3.9